# How can I remove elements with even no of re-occurrence in an array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var ar = ['a','a','a','b','e','e']
var charMap ={}
for(let char of ar){
    charMap[char] = charMap[char] +1 || 1
}
const result = [];
for(let ch in charMap){
    if(charMap[ch] %2 !== 0 ){
        result.push(Object.keys(ch))
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

The result should be like `['a','a','a','b']`, but I am getting something else.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `filter` method by passing a `callback` provided function as argument.

```js
var ar = ['a','a','a','b','e','e']
ar = ar.filter(function(item){
  return ar.filter(elem => elem == item).length %2 == 1;
});
console.log(ar);
```

Another approach is to use `filter` method in `combination` with `reduce`.

```js
var ar = ['a','a','a','b','e','e']
ar = ar.filter(function(item){
  return ar.reduce((pre, current) => (current == item) ? ++pre : pre, 0) % 2 == 1;
});
console.log(ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and count the values in advance. Then filter the array by checking the count.

```js
var array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'e'],
    result = array.filter(
        Map.prototype.get,
        array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 2) - 1), new Map)
    );

console.log(result);
```